# How do I pass information from my View to my Controller as a Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form and two SQL databases. The Form is to submit information to Database 1, but when the user enters information into the first field I need it to scan Database 2 for this data and populate a Description from this.

I currently have a button that will run script in the controller to retrieve this data. However, I don't know how to pass the first field as a parameter to the button onclick so it will use this to search the database.

Everything works in the controller but I don't know how to take information that is typed in an EditorFor text field and submit this to the button as a parameter. I have tried using the 'Model' to do this but my understanding of how this works is limited.

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Catalog", new { Number = Model.Number })'" ; />
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string catNo = "10004361")
        {
            IFS_Catalog_Products DatabaseScanner = new IFS_Catalog_Products();
            string catDesc = "";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"CONNECTION STRING";
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER = '" + catNo + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    catDesc = dr.GetString(0);
                    //break;
                }
                    con.Close();
            }
            DatabaseScanner.IFS_Catalog_Desc = catDesc;
            DatabaseScanner.IFS_Catalog_No = catNo;

            return View("Create", DatabaseScanner);
        }
```

The code compiles correctly and all aspects of the code work except for the Model.Number only ever passes a Null into the script.

I want to take the information from model.Number within the EditorFor field and use this within the statement.

Comment: you need to use POST controller method and let binder bind your properties automatically

Comment: check this link: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx

Comment: If I attach [HttpPost] and a Bind[(      )] within the controller I just receive HTTP404 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the POST action like this:

1. your view:

   ```
   @model YOUR_MODEL    
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-4">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
       <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
   </div>
   ```

   }
2. your model:

   ```
   public class YOUR_MODEL
   {
       public string Number {get;set;}
   }
   ```
3. your controller

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Search(YOUR_MODEL model)
   {
       IFS_Catalog_Products DatabaseScanner = new IFS_Catalog_Products();
       string catDesc = "";

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
           con.ConnectionString = @"CONNECTION STRING";
           con.Open();

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER = '" + model.Number+ "'", con);
           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (dr.Read())
           {
               catDesc = dr.GetString(0);
               //break;
           }
               con.Close();
       }
       DatabaseScanner.IFS_Catalog_Desc = catDesc;
       DatabaseScanner.IFS_Catalog_No = catNo;

       return View("Create", DatabaseScanner);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Html.ActionLink` helper instead of button to achieve the goal, as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Catalog", new { catNo = Model.Number }, new { @class="btn btn-default" })
```

Comment: I have changed my button to the Syntax you have supplied but I am still having the same problem, The parameter passes an empty value to the controller :(

Comment: can you check the generated HTML from above code in browser? It should contain the `catNo` as `QueryString` parameter as : `/Catalog/Search?catNo=123`.

Comment: Really sorry, I am new to using a lot of these functions and I have no idea what that means or how to do it :l EDIT: I dont see any Query String on the end of the URL when running the Action.

Comment: Well, if you are using `Google Chrome`, you can check [here](https://designtlc.com/use-chrome-inspector-edit-website-css/) and see what `HTML` is generating. In my case it is generating: `<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Catalog/Search?catNo=123">Search</a>`. Let me know what are you getting.